# Function that returns #t if expr is a valid boolean expression in racket

Tags: racket

expr = variable | bool-literal | not-expr | and-expr | or-expr .

```
    variable = a symbol v for which (is-vble? v) returns #t .

    bool-literal = "t" | "f" .

    not-expr = "(" "not" expr ")" .

    and-expr = "(" expr "and" expr ")" .

    or-expr = "(" expr "or" expr ")" .

    implication-expr = "(" expr "-->" expr ")" .
```

Implement the function (is-bool-expr? expr) that returns #t if expr is a valid boolean expression (as defined above), and #f otherwise. For example:

> (is-bool-expr? 't)
>
> ## t
>
> (is-bool-expr? '(t or (not f)))
>
> ## t
>
> (is-bool-expr? '((p and (p --> f)) --> q))
>
> ## t
>
> (is-bool-expr? '((p and (p --> f)) --> q))
>
> ## t
>
> (is-bool-expr? '(cheese shoes string))
>
> ## f

Comment: What have you tried so far? please post your code.

Comment: You need "boolean?" function